# Excel VBA running a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to run a macro which will update to extracts by selecting today()-1 in slicers with Macro. But I can't get it work.

I've tried to get date from cell value, and tried with Date and Now functions too. None of them worked. Anyone with any idea?

I get:

- Run-time error '1004' String can't be converted to type date.
  or
- Run-time error '1004' The item couldn't be found in OLAP Cube.

```
Sub Update_date()
'
' Update_date Macro
'
    Dim MyDate As Range
    Set MyDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Slicers").Range("D2")
'
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ship_Date").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array _
        ( _
        "[Sales Orders].[Ship Date].MyDate")
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ship_Date1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array _
        ( _
        "[Sales Orders].[Ship Date].MyDate") 
End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: It accepts "[Sales Orders].[Ship Date].&[2021-11-17T00:00:00]"), if I type it in the place of MyDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Update_date()
'
' Update_date Macro
'
'
' Update_date Macro
'
    Dim MyDate As Range
    Dim MyDate2
    
    Set MyDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Slicers").Range("D2")
    MyDate2 = Format(MyDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")             ' <- Had to convert date to this format. 
'
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ship_Date").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array _
        ( _
        "[Sales Orders].[Ship Date].&[" & MyDate2 & "]")
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ship_Date1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array _
        ( _
        "[Sales Orders].[Ship Date].&[" & MyDate2 & "]")

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).